# Deserialize Kotlin enum while ignoring unknown values

Tags: kotlin, serialization, enums, fallback

I have an enum that I'd like to deserialize from JSON using kotlinx.serialization while ignoring unknown values. This is the enum

```
@Serializable
enum class OperatingMode {
    Off, On, Auto
}
```

What I mean by ignoring unknowns is if I have a mode or modes in a JSON object which are not in that enum, they should be treated as absent:

```json
{"foo":"bar","mode":"Banana"}
// same as
{"foo":"bar"}

{"modes":["Off","On","Banana"]}
// same as
{"modes":["Off","On"]}
```

I got this to work by writing custom serializers, but it seems quite verbose for such a simple task

```
internal object OperatingModeSafeSerializer : KSerializer<OperatingMode?> {
    override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("OperatingMode", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: OperatingMode?) {
        // safe because @Serializable skips null fields
        encoder.encodeString(value!!.name)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): OperatingMode? {
        val string = decoder.decodeString()
        return try {
            OperatingMode.valueOf(string)
        } catch (_: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }
}

internal object OperatingModeSafeListSerializer: KSerializer<List<OperatingMode>> {
    private val delegateSerializer = ListSerializer(OperatingModeSafeSerializer)
    override val descriptor = delegateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<OperatingMode> {
        return decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer).filterNotNull()
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: List<OperatingMode>) {
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer, value)
    }
}
```

Then in each object which is deserializing `OperatingMode` I can add

```
@Serializable(with = OperatingModeSafeSerializer::class) // or
@Serializable(with = OperatingModeSafeListSerializer::class)
```

to ignore unknowns.

### Problems

1. This is a huge amount of code. I expect to have more enums for which I will need the exact same behavior and I really don't want to copy-paste this for each one. I don't know how to make this approach generic because these are objects which can't be generic and `@Serializable(with = ...)` needs a compile-time constant.
2. Ideally I'd want this behavior to be encapsulated in the enum itself, so that anything deserializing an `OperatingMode` will ignore unknowns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to refactor the approach in my question to avoid most of the code duplication.

```
open class SafeSerializer<T>(
    private val serializer: KSerializer<T>
): KSerializer<T?> {
    override val descriptor = serializer.descriptor

    // safe because @Serializable skips null fields
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: T?) = encoder.encodeSerializableValue(serializer, value!!)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): T? = try {
        decoder.decodeSerializableValue(serializer)
    } catch (_: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
    
open class NonNullListSerializer<T>(
    serializer: KSerializer<T?>
): KSerializer<List<T>> {
    private val delegateSerializer = ListSerializer(serializer)
    override val descriptor = delegateSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: List<T>) = encoder.encodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer, value)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<T> = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(delegateSerializer).filterNotNull()
}
```

Then for each enum you want to deserialize in this way, you simply declare

```
object OperatingModeSafeSerializer: SafeSerializer<OperatingMode>(OperatingMode.serializer())
object OperatingModeSafeListSerializer: NonNullListSerializer<OperatingMode>(OperatingModeSafeSerializer)
```

**N.B.** this probably only works with basic types like enums. If you try to use `SafeSerializer` with a complex type, the decoder might throw an exception in the middle of parsing a structure such as a JSON array or object. Catching that error will leave the decoder in an invalid state. One option would be to change `deserialize` to first decode a generic JSON element without catching errors, *then* decode that to `T` while catching, but that's at the cost of tightly coupling the serializer to JSON.

If kotlinx.serialization had less greedy parsers that tried to fully consume elements before throwing, this would be a non-issue.

Answer (score 7):

For now I think that the only way would be to use `coerceInputValues` option with default value of enum field to be null like in this example:

```
@Serializable
enum class OperatingMode {
    Off, On, Auto
}

@Serializable
data class Foo(val name: String, val mode: OperatingMode? = null)

private val jsonFormat = Json {coerceInputValues = true}

fun main() {
    val jsonString = """{"name":"ignored","mode":"AnotherOption"}"""
    val foo = jsonFormat.decodeFromString<Foo>(jsonString)
    println(foo)
}
```

Comment: Well that's much shorter, but it doesn't solve problem #2 because I have to make sure I configure each decoder correctly to avoid an exception.

Comment: I also don't see how to use this with `List<OperatingMode>` because I don't want it to fall back to a default value, I want it to parse the whole list and ignore only certain elements